# C library struct in C#

Tags: c#, struct, interop

So I'd like to write a spotify desktop app. Trouble is the spotify API is written in C, and I'd like to write it in C# because I know C# better. I realize I'll need to use P/Invoke and marshalling of structs, and I've done some reading on both of these topics.
My problem is that there is a number of structs (e.g. sp_session) which have no definition in the api.h file.
Is it possible to write a kind of Interop to the library if this is the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [codeplex](http://libspotifydotnet.codeplex.com/) project might be of some use.